# What does "fabulism" mean when used to describe one's accomplishments?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

In this [recent article in Science](https://www.science.org/content/article/after-misconduct-claims-star-botanist-has-second-paper-retracted), a botanist is reported as accused

> of apparent plagiarism, **fabulism** about his professional accomplishments, and fabrication or manipulation of data.

There is no definition for "fabulism" in MW or Dictionary.com, but there is a definition for "fabulist" as one who invents fables, with "liar" as a synonym.

In the quote given above, does "fabulism" imply the fabrication of lies or something milder, like the *embellishment* or *exaggeration* of one's accomplishments?

Comment: I don't think there's a clear distinction between fabrication and exaggeration; fabulism (or more usually fabulist) can refer to either, and it's common to use euphemisms when accusing somebody of lying ("economical with the truth", etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YourDictionary site at https://www.yourdictionary.com/fabulism gives the meaning "A form of magic realism in which fantastical elements are placed into an everyday setting".

In this context the word sounds to me to be stronger than merely lying. It is said that a good liar sticks close to the truth, but *fabulism* suggests that there is no realistic connection with the real world.

Comment: The quote appears to fit recent political winners., too. Not just raising false flags, but inventing lofty resumes whole cloth, or am I mixing my semaphores?

Answer (score 1):

A fabulist or one who practices fabulism is one who creates fables or fabulous accounts of their accomplishments. They are spinning a tale of fantastic works and successes when their achievements are far from those described. They are to be gratefully acknowledged but quietly put aside.